# Let $a_0>0$. If $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+a_n}$. Show that the sequence $a_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Let $a_0>0$. If $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+a_n}$. Show that the sequence $a_n$ converges.**

It's obvious that the sequence is bounded by $1$, but I can't show it is monotonic. I tried to start different values, and then sometimes is increasing, and sometimes is decreasing. Thus, I tried to use another way to approach by the following observation: 
$$
|a_{n+1}-a_n|=|\frac{1}{1+a_n}-\frac{1}{1+a_{n-1}}| = \frac{|a_n-a_{n-1}|}{|1+a_{n}||1+a_{n-1}|}.
$$
Hence, we notice that it is a contraction mapping. If we know 
$$
|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|<k|a_n-a_{n-1}|
$$
for some $k<1$, then we can deduce that the sequence converges. However, I can't have nice estimate for the term $|1+a_n+a_{n-1}+a_{n}a_{n-1}|$, and only obtain
$$
|a_{n+1}-a_n|<|a_n-a_{n-1}|,
$$ which is not good enough. Can someone give me some idea to deal with this? Thanks.

Comment: Try approach $a_{n+1}/a_{n}$ since your sequence is positive.

Comment: Another hint: $\;a_{n+1}-a_{n-1} = -\, \cfrac{1}{a_{n-1}+2}\lt 0\,$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We prove the sequence converges to the unique positive number $L$ such that $L = \frac{1}{1+L}$ [such $L$ can be solved for using the quadratic formula]. Indeed, note that for any $n \in \mathbb N$, \begin{align*}
\lvert a_{n+1} - L \rvert &= \left\lvert \frac{1}{1+a_n} - \frac{1}{1+L} \right \rvert\\
&= \left\lvert \frac{1+L -(1+a_{n})}{(1+L)(1+a_n)} \right \rvert \\
&\le \frac{1}{1+L} \lvert a_n - L\rvert.
\end{align*} Recursively applying this bound we find that $$\lvert a_{n+1} - L \rvert \le\frac{1}{(1+L)^{n+1}} \lvert a_0 - L\rvert $$ whence sending $n \to \infty$ shows that $a_n \to L$.

Comment: I used the similar approach to solve this exact same problem but my prof said how can we use the identity that we get from assuming the sequence converges. I mean we don't know yet if this converges or not so we can not use L=1/(1+L). I don't understand what other way we can solve it

Comment: @User8128 This answer does *not* assume that $a_n\to L$. It *proves* it.