# suppose $a_0>0$ and $a_{n+1}=1/(1+a_n)$ . Show that this sequence converges and find its limit.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

suppose $a_0>0$ and $a_{n+1}=1/(1+a_n)$ . Show that this sequence converges and find its limit. I have shown by induction that $a_n$ is bounded by (0,1].Now I am struggling to show that a_n is decreasing sequence. If I'm able to show then I can easily prove the limit is the golden ratio. Can anybody say how I can show a_n is a decreasing sequence?

This question was asked before and I used a similar approach that was mentioned to solve this problem but my professor asked how can we use the identity that we get from assuming the sequence converges. I mean we don't know yet if this converges or not so we can not use L=1/(1+L). I don't understand what other way we can solve it

Comment: Careful: the limit would not be the golden ratio $\phi = (1+\sqrt{5})/2$ because that's outside of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yeah Sorry, it would be $\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: Note that $a_n$ need not be a decreasing sequence in order to converge. In fact, if you listed out some values, you'd find that $a_n$ is alternatively above/below the limit.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for pointing this out. I was thinking only one way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $a_0&gt;0$. If $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+a_n}$. Show that the sequence $a_n$ converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215002/let-a-00-if-a-n1-frac11a-n-show-that-the-sequence-a-n-converge) - got this from [hellofriends' comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695287/suppose-a-00-and-a-n1-1-1a-n-show-that-this-sequence-converges-and#comment9934849_4695287). As for determining the limit after proving it converges, just solve for $L$ where $L = \frac{1}{1+L}$.